# Java Web-services. How to create a web service in Java console application?

Tags: java, web-services

I have the question...
How to create a web service in Java console application **without using the web server**?
Could you give me an example or a detailed response ...

Comment: It's not impossible. But you would have to write an entire http interpreter. Why won't you just use a web server?

Comment: At the moment I'm looking for an opportunity to do without a web server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way I can think of would be to go RPC style as described in the example below :

http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-hello-world-example/

Though if you prefer jax-rs, the spec documentation would be a good read :

https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0/apidocs/index.html

Comment: Thank you, I did not find here any dependencies with Maven and Tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, what you meant is: *How to create a **standalone** Java application* which serves web-requests, without dealing with servlet-containers?.

1) you could cheat and use [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/), which produces a single *jar*. But it has an embedded Tomcat/Jetty. So it acts like you wanted, but it is not without a servlet-container per se: but it runs without a direct dependecy to one

2) you could take a look into [Spark](http://www.sparkjava.com/). A lightweight webframework, inspired by [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/). Which is without the dependency to an *embedded* Tomcat.

3) You get your hands (really really) *dirty* and take a look at [HttpServer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpServer.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSP and JQuery to develop a web application instead of using pure JAVA. Use HTTP server or interpreter.